# Python Kivy language color property

Tags: python, kivy

Does Kivy language support hex color values such as

> **#F05F40**

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kivy has `utils` module with [get_color_from_hex](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.utils.html#kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex) function that do job:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils


<Widget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex('#F05F40')
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Note, that you should [import](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#special-syntaxes) module in kvlang.

Comment: Or go for [`kivy.utils.rgba`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.utils.html#kivy.utils.rgba), which provides this and a little bit extended behavior with less characters (as a more complex layout in kv is line width hungry) :)